# What's the meaning of p-values which produced by feature selection (i.e. chi2 method)?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, feature-selection

Recently, I have used sklearn(a python meachine learning library) to do a short-text classification task. I found that SelectKBest class can choose K best of features. However, the first argument of SelectKBest is a score function, which "taking two arrays X and y, and returning a pair of arrays (scores, pvalues)". I know that scores, but what is the meaning of pvalues?

Comment: This is better moved to SO's sister site for statistics [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), where it has lots of posts under its own tag [p-value](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value). Or else the beta Data Science site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general the p-value indicates how probable a given outcome or a more extreme outcome is under the null hypothesis. In your case of feature selection, the null hypothesis is something like *this feature contains no information about the prediction target*, where *no information* is to be interpreted in the sense of the scoring method: If your scoring method tests e.g. univariate linear interaction (`f_classif`, `f_regression` in `sklearn.feature_selection` are options for your scoring function), then the null hypothesis says that this linear interaction is not present.

**TL;DR** The p-value of a feature selection score indicates the probability that **this score or a higher score**  would be obtained if this variable showed no interaction with the target.

Another general statement: **scores** are *better if greater*, **p-values** are *better if smaller* (and **losses** are *better if smaller*)

Comment: Actually the p-value expresses the probability that the score *or any lower score* would be obtained under the assumption of independence: it's the area under the tail of a distribution. It's also worth mentioning that the p-values are used by `SelectFdr` and friends (fdr = false discovery rate), while the scores are used by `SelectKBest` and `SelectPercentile`, and that the API was modeled after the one in `scipy.stats`. +1 for the rest of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My description is indeed rather inexact. The probability of attaining any exact value in a continuous distribution is 0 :). Before I edit it: In the case of F-score, the p-values represent the upper tail integral, rather than the lower one, right? I.e. the p-value indicates the probability that this F-score or any *higher* score is obtained, if I am not missing something entirely.

Comment: Right, my mistake, it's "or higher" not "or lower".